# How to check Bacula version

Tags: bacula

How do I check the Bacula version?
I installed Bacula using the `apt-get install` command on Ubuntu. I want to know the version I am using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this:

```
apt-cache policy bacula
```

This will show you the version of bacula that is currently installed, as well as all versions of bacula available to you from all repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a complicated question to answer because there are a lot of pieces involved, pieces that are different depending on what the purpose of the machine is and what versions of Bacula (or Baculum) you're dealing with. Even on the same machine, it's possible to have several parts with different versions (which may or may not be a problem—it's complicated).

For example, both my main Bacula server (where all the backups are stored) and the machines it backs up have some version of the package bacula-common installed, but only my main server has bacula-mysql installed, and nothing has the package just named "bacula" installed.

### Apt

Depending on your setup, you may be able to use `apt-cache policy package-name` to get a list of what was installed via apt or could be installed:

```bash
# All Bacula packages
apt-cache policy bacula*
# A specific one
apt-cache policy bacula-common
```

This was helpful when I was trying to upgrade Bacula. It's also the only way I know of to check the version of Baculum (the web interface).

Note that upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 will make it impossible to find Bacula in the Ubuntu repos (thus returning an error even if you had previously installed Bacula this way and preventing Bacula from working) and in 20.04 the highest version available is Bacula via these repos is 9. Because of this, I had to edit `/etc/sources.list` (or a subfile like `/etc/sources.list.d/baculum.list`) to pull from Bacula's own repos.

Note also that the Bacula apt packages you need vary based on what version you're running. Bacula 9 has bacula-sd and bacula-director for example, but Bacula 13 has you install the bacula-dir package and no bacula-sd package—more on these missing packages later.

### Command line tools

The Bacula command line tools (e.g., `bconsole`) accept the question mark flag (`-?`) as a way to print out the version (and information about the other flags). While there's no support for `-v`, typing in an invalid command like that will also show this same help message. You can also run `bconsole` alone to start up the console, which will also show the version (but usually requires more permissions than `-?` on account of having to load the conf files and you also have to exit it). The version returned by `bconsole` should be the same as in `apt-cache` (if installed that way), though they are in slightly different formats—the former gives the date of publication for that version of the software, for example.

For your copy/pasting convenience:

```
bconsole -?
```

This proved challenging to use in a script where I only wanted to see the version. I ended up with this monstrosity which is a little verbose since it outputs the entire line with the version:

```bash
version=$(bconsole -? >(grep 'Version') 2>(grep 'Version'))
```

#### Other versions

In addition to the above, I soon realized that there are important binaries that didn't have an installed apt package and couldn't be accessed by just typing in a command like `bconsole`. For example, bacula-sd is installed with apt if you have Bacula 9, but there is no such package for Bacula 13. In Bacula 9, the binaries seem to have been in `/usr/sbin/`, while in Bacula 13 they're in `/opt/bacula/bin/`.

### Files

Something else worth noting is that for me many files in Bacula 9 were installed in `/etc/bacula/` while everything in Bacula 13 got installed into `/opt/bacula/`. This means that anything that references something in `/etc/bacula/` (such as `/etc/init.d/bacula-sd`) is from the version 9 installation.

Meanwhile, Baculum for me is in `/etc/baculum/`—it did not move when I installed the most recent version (Baculum 11).